How to refer to subdirs and style files in github.io
I want to make a github.io page using LaTeXML. I understood that the life starts in its /docs subdirectory. I wanted to create website with theoretical background in /www, separated from the programming stuff and its docs in /docs, but as I experience the redirection is made to a subdirectory parallel with the project directory instead of the requested subdirectory and also the style files which are in the upstream subdirectory of /docs do not work (probably they are not at the right place).
What are the rules for handling subdirectories (on my local machine, the site works perfectly)
